# Why it is better to find errors at compile-time rather than at run-time?

Tags: compiler-errors

Why it is better to find errors at compile-time rather than at run-time? I searched for same topics here and in other places but didn`t find a decent answer.

Comment: It's quicker to do it at compile time?

Answer (score 6):

It's generally true that the earlier in the software development process that you find bugs the quicker/easier/cheaper it is to fix them. Typically a compiler error or warning points you at exactly the line in the code where the problem lies, whereas locating a bug at run-time will usually be a much more lengthy and laborious process. Furthermore, it may also be the case that the bug does not show up for some time (a "latent" bug), so you may need to expend additional effort at some point in the future in providing customer support, shipping software updates with the bug fix, deal with resulting loss of reputation, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, since the compiler goes through all your code every time you compile, any errors it can detect will be found automatically at every compilation.

Finding errors runtime means you have to run all the code to detect the errors, which can be tricky, especially with code that has many conditionally executed branches. Also, pinpointing the exact location of the errors can be very tricky.

In the end it comes down to finding the bugs as soon as possible, so you can fix them while the code is fresh in your mind.

Answer (score 1):

Also, adding to what @Paul R said, the compile errors are "easier" to notice (you just compile your code and voilà), while the run time errors might be particular to a use case scenario, which might crash your system while it was deployed. Think about the impact...

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of errors, compile time and run time. Preferably, you want your errors to occur at compile time because those are much easier to diagnose and correct.

Basically a compile time error means that the code written cannot be built because there is a syntax error (typo) or type error (calling or using a variable type in the wrong way), etc and the compiler cannot continue. Compilers these days though do their best to identify all types of errors even potential run time errors because it is much cheaper and less time consuming to correct these problems while you are writing your code as opposed to during the debugging process. Usually in a compiler that can do rudimentary "run time" analysis you will receive warnings, which is the compiler's way of telling you that it thinks your code is jacked up. It still builds in a warning scenario but warnings are always something you should pay attn to.

Run time errors occur because although the code may be correct, the logic is not or the compiler has no way of knowing during the build the parameter(s) going into the code (think user input). Examples of run time errors are infinite loops, out of bounds errors, type errors (think user entering a string when asked for a number) and many others.

The bottom line is that any time we can know about an error as they are generated as opposed to after we are done, we can keep our code cleaner and more effective. I hope this helps. :)